# how to catch right mouse click event on echarts graph element?

Tags: echarts

`myChart.on('click', function(params) {
    console.log(params);
})`

the code given above handles whenever you click a chart element, it returns necessary object information. However, this is for **left mouse click**. What i wanted is to handle right mouse click for echarts graph. Is this feature possible with echarts? Thank you in advance

See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/donalmighty/dptnevqh/112/

Answer (score 0):

Well, they said they won't support `rightClick` event, since it's a web lib not client lib.

Detail in this [issue](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/939)

> rightclick就算了，这是传统pc而不是web思维的交互习惯